# Using numeric value as a look up with index match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, lookup, index-match

Using number of user appearance as lookup value to find the name of a user with INDEX MATCH

..
.............................

The general motif of this was to display a pie chart showing the top 5 most active user
And I can't use pivot tables because this chart will be connected to a userform and pivottables require to be refreshed on every change of data...

In my Table, there's  a column that stores the name of the current user making entries

I decided to get the top 5 active userName.
First, I must get the Unique usernames from my table
I extracted the names from the login sheet that houses only active users.
So on column A, there is username and on column B, I used COUNTIF to get the number of occurrences on my table with the username in column A.

... then I moved ahead to use another helper column to find the top 5 number of appearance LARGE(B:B, Rows($C$2:C2) ) to get the first highest 5 number of user appearance.

Now the problem comes when I want to get the names of the users that have the first 5 highest number of appearance.. using INDEX AND MATCH.
If a number of appearance is repeated by a user, INDEX MATCH repeats the first matching result.
E.g.
Mark 7.
Rachel 6.
....
If Rachel makes an extra entry and ties 7 with Mark.
INDEX MATCH returns second largest as Mark instead of Rachel.

I would like to know how to find the next name that has the repeated number.

I tried using a second Match as column number in Index Match, matching the userName as second criteria
I tried using aggregate function with Index
Kept getting N/A or #Ref With all my attempts.

Is there a function, and how to use the function with index - to find the next username that has the same number ??

Also.. there is the possibility where all top 5 user will have the same score.....
Would it be possible to return all 5 unique names with the same score, even though the score is the lookup value??

Comment: Sort your data by score (descending). Then return the first five. If you have Excel 365 you can use the SORT function, then INDEX and return rows 1-5

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld .. I realise I must include my initial steps to aid better understanding of my question ..My apologies, I've updated my Question

Comment: If my suggestion isn't useful, I suggest you edit your question **after** reading through the the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Extremely useful and It helped! I wasn't sure how I presented the question. Thank you

Comment: If you have developed a solution, you can present it as the answer, and even mark it as such after a while.

Comment: `=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$26)+COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)-1` will give different ranking even if they have same score.